# How to solve 100^1000 in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, logic

This Question is from Hacker Earth website as follow

Input: First line contains t, the number of test cases. After that t lines follow each containing a pair of space separated integers i.e. a and b.

Output: For each test case, you need to print the sum of digits in a^b.

Constraints:

1<=t<=20000

1<=a<=100

1<=b<=1000

Sample Input (Plaintext Link)

```
5
2 10
3 3
5 2
2 7
100 1000
```

Sample Output (Plaintext Link)

```
7
9
7
11
1
```

Explanation: Consider the first test case.
             2^10 = 1024

```
         Now, 1 + 0 + 2 + 4 = 7
         So, output for this test case is 7.
```

Now I have solve this problem as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define test_max 20000
#define a_max 100
#define b_max 10000
long int power(int,int);
long int check_num(int,int);
int main()
{
    int t;
    long int i,rem,j=0,sum=0;
    long int pr;


scanf("%d",&t);
int a[t],b[t];

    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        scanf("%d",&b[i]);

        if(a[i]>a_max||a[i]<=0||b[i]>b_max||b[i]<=0)
        {
        //  printf("Please Check the Enter number limitation");

            exit(0);
        }

    }

    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        int check=0;

        check=check_num(a[i],b[i]);
         if(check==0)
         {
            pr=power(a[i],b[i]);
            //printf("%d\t%d\t%ld\t",a[i],b[i],pr);
            while(pr!=0)
            {
            rem=pr%10;
            sum=sum+rem;
            pr=pr/10;
            }
            printf("%d\n",sum);
            sum=0;
        }
        else if(check==1)
        {
            printf("1\n");

        }
    }

return 0;

}

long int check_num(int a,int b)
{
    if(a==100||a==10||a==1) return 1;
    else return 0;

}

long int power(int n,int p)
{

    int i;
    long int num=n;
    for(i=1;i<p;i++)
    {
       num=num*n;

    }
    return num;

}
```

But it's not a perfect answer. Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

The link of this problem is here: [HERE](http://www.hackerearth.com/codex-10-7/algorithm/chesters-revenge-4/)

and I know the `100^1000` is not possible without using any library and I just have to avoid this but how?

Comment: Is there a real question here?  This seems to be more of a coding competition.

Comment: @HotLicks yes it is but competition was finished and my submission is no valid so that's why I am asking this question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generally speaking, When you talk about large numbers, you have 3 main options:

**1)** Use a **library** that manipulates big numbers

**2)** Implement your own functions for big numbers (use **arrays** to store the numbers - the length will be equal to the number of digits)

**3)** Find a **Math** approach

I will add some details for the 3<sup>rd</sup> approach, because the 1<sup>st</sup> and the 2<sup>nd</sup> are not very complicated.

If you need only the sum for those digits, try to avoid calculating that big number.

Think about **logarithms** and their [properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities) when you work with large numbers.

For example, your particular case can be written in the following form:

```
100^1000 = (10^2)^1000 = 10^(2*1000) * 1 = 10^2000 + 0 = 10^2000 * 1
```

You know that the first part (`10^2000`) only adds some zeros => it doesn't influence your result (sum). So, you can try to split that big numbers in 2 parts ( a part that doesn't influence the sum and a useful part for the sum - `1` ).

How can you do this using logarithms for a more general problem? The following observation can generalize the things that were mentioned above:

```
a^x = 10^lg(a^x) = 10^(x*lg(a))
where lg = log in base 10
```

Then you can write your number as: `10^c * k` or `10^c + k` or `10^c - k`, etc. depending on your numbers.

This explanation is just for guidance, to give you a taste. But the idea is the same: think about a mathematical solution based on some properties before you try other approaches.

Comment: so how I convert it into program or in logic In my above c program ?

Answer (score 0):

`100^1000` is too large a number to fit into a `long`, or any other basic number type.

You need to pick a *big integer* (also called *big number*) library that helps you manage arbirtrarily big numbers.

Try [`libGMP`](https://gmplib.org/), it's widely used.